# How many ways To Connect Database Server using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, oracle, sqlite

I want to know how many ways we can get Server Database using JavaScript like using mongo db ,SQLite or any other ways to connect Server database

Comment: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29), to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about client-side Javascript, there's no way<sup>1</sup>.

You have to send messages (perhaps using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)) to scripts running on a server which will then connect to the database.

---

<sup>1</sup> actually, there *was* [WebDB](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) for access to a local SQLite engine in the HTML5 specs, but it got deprecated.

Comment: You could directly access CouchDB, since it provides a REST API.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak for responding me ,I totally agree with you i tried  to explain  same thing to the client but some how he knew that we could connect to  db Server using JS he had given option monjo db to me i never  heard and worked on monjo ,Do you have any idea how does it works.

Comment: @FelixKling true, but I wouldn't want to risk it on a real application without some middleware to mediate access between clients and server.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I have gone through your suggestion to use CouchDB. I am working on how it use and all,Let's see how it will fulfill my requirments

Comment: @Devendra: I'm not necessarily suggesting to use it. It depends entirely on your use case. CouchDB is a document-oriented, no-SQL DB. This might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for valuable suggestion I have used local database based on browser supports using following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>SQL Storage</title>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div align="center">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" /> First name:<input type="text"
            id="firstName" /><br /> Last name:<input type="text" id="lastName" /><br />
        Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" /><br />
        <button onClick="resetForm()">Reset Form</button>
        <button onClick="updateRecord()">Update</button>
        <button onClick="insertRecord()">Insert</button>
        <button onClick="dropTable()">Drop Table</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    var id = document.getElementById('id');
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone');

    var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, phone TEXT)";
    var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";
    var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Contacts (firstName, lastName, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    var updateStatement = "UPDATE Contacts SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, phone = ? WHERE id = ?";
    var deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id=?";
    var dropStatement = "DROP TABLE Contacts";
    try {
        var db = openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
    var dataset;
    createTable();

    function onError(tx, error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    function showRecords() {
        results.innerHTML = '';
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
                dataset = result.rows;
                for ( var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    item = dataset.item(i);
                    results.innerHTML += '<li>' + item['lastName'] + ' , '
                    item['firstName'] + ' <a href="#"     onclick="loadRecord('
                            + i + ')">edit</a>  '
                            + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id']
                            + ')">delete</a></li>';
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function createTable() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], showRecords, onError);
        });
    }

    function insertRecord() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [ firstName.value, lastName.value,
                    phone.value ], loadAndReset, onError);
        });
    }

    function loadRecord(i) {
        var item = dataset.item(i);
        firstName.value = item['firstName'];
        lastName.value = item['lastName'];
        phone.value = item['phone'];
        id.value = item['id'];
    }

    function updateRecord() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(updateStatement, [ firstName.value, lastName.value,
                    phone.value, id.value ], loadAndReset, onError);
        });
    }

    function deleteRecord(id) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, [ id ], showRecords, onError);
        });
        resetForm();
    }

    function dropTable() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(dropStatement, [], showRecords, onError);
        });
        resetForm();
    }

    function loadAndReset() {
        resetForm();
        showRecords();
    }

    function resetForm() {
        firstName.value = '';
        lastName.value = '';
        phone.value = '';
        id.value = '';
    }
</script>
</html>
```